# Seeking closed form for infinite sum $\sum \limits_{ n=1 }^{ \infty }{ \frac { { \left(n! \right) }^{ 2 } }{ { n }^{ 3 }(2n)! } }$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, factorial, closed-form

$\displaystyle \sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { \left(n! \right) }^{ 2 } }{ { n }^{ 3 }(2n)! }  }$ is approximately $.5229461921333351$ but I've been assured that there is a closed form for this infinite series that involves the TriGamma and  Zeta functions but it is not unique. I found one candidate result which is:
$$ \frac{ \pi \sqrt{3}}{72} \Big[3 \psi_{1} \left(\frac{1}{3} \right) - \psi_{1} \left(\frac{5}{6} \right) \Big]- \frac{4}{3} \zeta(3) $$

My friend (tormentor) has challenged me to find other such expressions. I know how to transform the look of such expressions if the Gamma function is involved by using functional equations like $\Gamma(x) = \Gamma(1+x)/x$ so I suspect he knows a similar result for the PolyGamma functions. I just can not find the information.  By trial and error, I did find that $3 \psi_{1}(1)=\psi_{1}(1/2)$

Comment: Probably not the closed-form you want, but using the series for $\arcsin^2(x)$ we can write the sum as the integral: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3{2n\choose n}} = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{4\arcsin^2\left(x\right)}{x}{\rm d}x$. Putting this integral through Mathematica gives (after simplifying using [these identities](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/17/ShowAll.html)) gives one possible answer $$-\frac{2}{3} i \pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)-\frac{4 \zeta(3)}{3}+\frac{i \pi ^3}{54}$$ Can probably be simplified further.

Comment: By playing around with it I found an identity that you can try to prove which can be used to come up with a different form for the answer you have found: $$2\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right) - 7\psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) - 2\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) + \psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right) = 0$$

Comment: Surprisingly, it's very close to the value of $$\frac{\pi}{e}-\frac{\pi^3}{49}$$

Comment: Agreement to the 8th decimal place is amazingly close !! How did you discover that @Sophie Agnesi ?

Comment: @BobKadylo I build a program for that. I'm able to get it at least to 26th decimal place but it's only a good approximation, not a real closed-form.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum _{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{n!}^{2} \over n^{3}\pars{2n}!}} & =
\sum _{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{2n + 1}} =
\sum _{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}\,\ \overbrace{%
{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{n} \over \Gamma\pars{2n + 1}}}
^{\ds{\mathrm{B}\pars{n + 1,n}}}
\\[4mm] & =
\sum _{n = 1}^{\infty}\
{1 \over n^{2}}\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\pars{1 - x}^{n - 1}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\mathrm{B}\pars{n + 1,n}}}\ =\
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over x}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\bracks{x\pars{1 - x}}^{\, n} \over n^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[4mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x\bracks{1 - x}} \over x}\,\dd x =
-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x\bracks{1 - x}}\pars{1 - 2x}
\,\dd x
 \\[4mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,
\braces{-\,{\ln\pars{1 - x\bracks{1 - x}} \over x\pars{1 - x}}}
\pars{1 - 2x}\,\dd x
\\[4mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[4mm] & =
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\,\mathcal{I}_{1}}}\ -\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\,\mathcal{I}_{2}}}
\\[4mm] & = \,\mathcal{I}_{1} - \,\mathcal{I}_{2}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

1. $\ds{\large\,\mathcal{I}_{1} =\ ?}$.
\begin{align}
\,\mathcal{I}_{1} & =
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\ds{\quad%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over x}\,\dd x\quad}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array} =
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x^{3} \over 1 + x}\,{\dd x \over x}
\\[4mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x^{3}} \over x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\ & =
{1 \over 9}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x}\,\dd x =
-\,{8 \over 9}
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[4mm] & =
{8 \over 9}
\int_{0}^{-1}\bracks{-\,{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}}\,\ln\pars{-x}\,\dd x =
{8 \over 9}
\int_{0}^{-1}\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\ln\pars{-x}\,\dd x =
-\,{8 \over 9}
\int_{0}^{-1}{\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x 
\\[4mm] & =
-\,{8 \over 9}\int_{0}^{-1}\,\mathrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{x}\,\dd x =
-\,{8 \over 9}\,\mathrm{Li}_{3}\pars{-1} =
-\,{8 \over 9}\pars{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{3}} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{3}}}
\\[4mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}}
 \end{align}
\begin{equation}
\,\mathcal{I}_{1} =
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\ds{\quad%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over x}\,\dd x\quad}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array} =
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\ds{\quad{2 \over 3}\,\zeta\pars{3}\quad}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

---

2. $\ds{\large\,\mathcal{I}_{2} =\ ?}$.
\begin{align}
\,\mathcal{I}_{2} & =
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\ds{\quad%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over x}\,\dd x\quad}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array} =
-\int_{0}^{1}\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1}\,\dd x
\\[4mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x}\,{2x - 1 \over x^{2} - x + 1}\,\dd x
\end{align}
The roots of $\ds{x^{2} - x + 1}$ are given by
$\ds{r = {1 + \root{3}\ic \over 2} = \expo{\pi\ic/3}}$ and $\ds{\ol{r}}$ such that
\begin{align}
{2x - 1 \over x^{2} - x + 1} & =
2\pars{{x - 1/2 \over x - r} - {x - 1/2 \over x - \ol{r}}}\,{1 \over r - \ol{r}}
=
2\,{1 \over 2\ic\,\Im\pars{r}}\,2\ic\,\Im\pars{x - 1/2 \over x - r}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over \root{3}}\,\Im\pars{2r - 1 \over x - r} = 2\,\Re\pars{1 \over x - r}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\,\mathcal{I}_{2} & =
2\,\Re\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x} \over x - r}\,\dd x} =
-2\,\Re\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}
{\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x} \over 1 - x/r}\,{\dd x \over r}} =
-2\,\Re\bracks{\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}
{\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{rx} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
2\,\Re\bracks{\left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{rx}\,
\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ \ol{r}} -
\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{rx}r\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
2\,\Re\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,{\ln\pars{1 - rx} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x +
\Re\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - rx} \over x}\,\dd x -
\Re\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x \over 1 - rx}\,{\dd x \over x}
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x +
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x -
\Re\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x \over 1 - rx}\,{\dd x \over x}
\end{align}
In the last integral, we'll make the
sub$\ds{\ldots {1 - rx \over 1 - x} \mapsto x}$ such that the whole integration is reduced to:
\begin{align}
\,\mathcal{I}_{2} & =
\Re\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x +
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x - \bracks{%
\Re\int_{1}^{0}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over -1 + x}\,\dd x -
\Re\int_{1}^{0}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over -r + x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x +
\Re\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}{\ln^{2}\pars{rx} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\end{align}
The remaining integrals can be evaluated by 'standard means'. For instance
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\int{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x} + 2\ln\pars{1 - x}
\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 - x} - 2\,\mathrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 - x}}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\int{\ln^{2}\pars{rx} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln^{2}\pars{rx} - 2\ln\pars{rx}
\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x} + 2\,\mathrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x}}
\end{array}\right.
$$
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\Re\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{2\pi \over 3}\,\Im\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{r} -
2\Re\,\mathrm{Li}_{3}\pars{r} + 2\
\overbrace{\mathrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1}}^{\ds{\zeta\pars{3}}}}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\Re\int_{0}^{\ol{r}}{\ln^{2}\pars{rx} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} &
\ds{2\,\Re\,\mathrm{Li}_{3}\pars{\ol{r}}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

With these results:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\ds{\quad\,\mathcal{I}_{2} =
2\zeta\pars{3} - {2 \pi \over 3}\,\Im\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{r}\,,\qquad
r = \half + {\root{3} \over 2}\,\ic = \expo{\pi\ic/3}\quad}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}\tag{3}
\end{equation}

---

With $\ds{\pars{1}, \pars{2}\ \mbox{and}\ \pars{3}}$, we'll arrive to the $\ds{\underline{final\ result}}$:
$$
\begin{array}{|rcl|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\ds{\quad\color{#f00}{\sum _{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{n!}^{2} \over n^{3}\pars{2n}!}}}
& \ds{=} &
\ds{\color{#f00}{{2 \pi \over 3}\,\Im\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{r} -
{4 \over 3 }\,\zeta\pars{3}}}\ds{\,\, \approx\,\, 0.5229\quad}
\\[3mm]
\ds{r} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{\expo{\pi\ic/3} = \half + {\root{3} \over 2}\,\ic}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

> In order to see the relation with the *Trigamma Function* $\ds{\Psi\, '}$, we can exploit the 'symmetries' of $\ds{\expo{\pi\ic/3}}$. Namely,

\begin{align}
\Im\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{r} & =
\Im\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{\pi\ic/3}} =
\Im\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\expo{n\pi\ic/3} \over n^{2}} =
\Im\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{\expo{\pars{3n + 1}\pi\ic/3} \over \pars{3n + 1}^{2}} +
{\expo{\pars{3n + 2}\pi\ic/3} \over \pars{3n + 2}^{2}} +
{\expo{\pars{3n + 3}\pi\ic/3} \over \pars{3n + 3}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\root{3} \over 2}\bracks{%
\sum_{n = 0}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{3n + 1}^{2}} +
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{3n + 2}^{2}}}
\end{align}
However,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{3n + z}^{2}} & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{6n + z}^{2}} -
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{6n + z + 2}^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 36}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + z/6}^{2}} -
{1 \over 36}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + z/6 + 1/3}^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 36}\,\Psi\, '\pars{z \over 6} -
{1 \over 36}\,\Psi\, '\pars{{z \over 6} + {1 \over 3}}
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
\Im\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\pars{r} & =
{\root{3} \over 72}\bracks{%
\Psi\, '\pars{1 \over 6} -\
\underbrace{\Psi\,'\pars{\half}}_{\ds{\pi^{2} \over 2}}\ +\
\Psi\, '\pars{1 \over 3} - \Psi \, '\pars{2 \over 3}}
\end{align}

Comment: Simply incredible.

Comment: @Felix Marin Direct and clever! (+1)

Comment: @tired Thanks for holy and for s...

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thanks a lot. It was a nightmare.

Comment: @nbubis Thanks. A lot of work.

Answer (score 3):

There is a few identities you could use $$\psi ^{(1)}\left(z\right)=\zeta \left(2,z\right)$$ $$\psi ^{(1)}(1-z)+\psi ^{(1)}(z)=\pi ^2 \csc ^2(\pi  z)$$ $$ \psi ^{(1)}(z+1)=\psi ^{(1)}(z)-\frac{1}{z^2}$$See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function).

Answer (score 3):

The series can be expressed in the form
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{n^3 \, (2n)!} &= \frac{1}{2} \, {}_{4}F_{3}\left(1,1,1,1; 2,2,\frac{3}{2}; \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, \left[ - \frac{8}{3} \, \zeta(3) + \frac{\pi}{4 \sqrt{3}} \, \psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) - \frac{\pi}{12 \sqrt{3}} \, \psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right) \right]
\end{align}

Comment: This is equivalent to the result I had found. Thanks for the confirmation !

Answer (score 2):

I am French and I research expressions of trigamma zeta 3 Catalan ...
it's very difficult but for your example, I propose $\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}\Psi\left(1,\frac{1}{3}\right)}{9}-\frac{2\sqrt{3}\pi^3}{27}-4\frac{\zeta(3)}{3}$. So I confirm the expression with MAPLE.