# Evaluating $\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1-x^4\right)}{x}\:dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How can i evaluate $$\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1-x^4\right)}{x}\:dx$$
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+%28ln%281-x%29ln%281-x%5E%284%29%29%29%2Fx) offers no closed form and it numerically approximates it to $1.07801$.

I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: see these two posts dealing with the same problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3319404/integral-int-01-frac-ln1-x-ln1x2xdx, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301156/the-closed-form-solution-of-the-family-sum-n-1-infty-sum-m-1-infty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3319404/integral-int-01-frac-ln1-x-ln1x2xdx)

Answer (score 1):

There is closed form for the antiderivative but it would require pages to write (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28Log%5B1+-+x%5D*Log%5B1+-+x%5E4%5D%29%2Fx%2Cx%5D)).

Using the bounds
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1-x^4\right)}{x}\:dx=\frac{67 }{32}\zeta (3)-\frac{\pi }{2}C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x^4)}{x}dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\int_0^1 x^{4n-1}\ln(1-x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{4n}}{4n^2}$$

use
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(2n)=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nf(n)\tag1$$

$$I=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{n^2}+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}}{n^2}=\frac12S_1+\frac12S_2$$

use (1) again for the $S_1$ and use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nf(2n)=\Re\sum_{n=1}^\infty i^n f(n)$ for $S_2$.

Hint: we need [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3366039) to calculate $S_2$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^2}x^{n}=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac12\ln x\ln^2(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$