# Closed form of $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=1} \left( {(-1)^n}\left( 1+n\ln(\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}) \right) \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, closed-form

I am trying to show $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=1} \left( {(-1)^n}\left( 1+n\ln(\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}) \right) \right)=\frac{2G}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$. I tried connecting this series to integrals in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant but was unable to link to any of them. I discovered the closed-form by using a piecewise function's Fourier series, however, I believe this is not a standard way. Do you have any ideas on this?

Comment: I am not sure if it helps but your sum is $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty{( - 1)^n \left( {1 - 2n\tanh ^{ - 1} \left({\frac{1}{{2n}}} \right)} \right)} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  {(-1)^n \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{-1}}{{(2k+1)(2n)^{2k} }}} }  \\ = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(2k + 1)2^{2k} }}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^{n - 1} }}{{n^{2k} }}} } =\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty  {\frac{{(1-2^{1-2k} )\zeta(2k)}}{{(2k+1)2^{2k} }}} \\= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\zeta (2k)}}{{(2k + 1)2^{2k} }}}-2\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{{\zeta(2k)}}{{(2k+1)2^{4k} }}}. 
$$

Comment: You can write the sums as integrals using the Laurent series of the cotangent, thus your sum is $$
\int_0^{1/2} {(1 - \pi s\cot (\pi s))ds}  - 4\int_0^{1/4} {(1 - \pi s\cot (\pi s))ds} 
\\  =  - \int_0^{1/2} {\pi s\cot (\pi s)}  + 4\int_0^{1/4} {\pi s\cot (\pi s)ds}  - \frac{1}{2}
\\ =  - \frac{{\log 2}}{2} + \frac{{4G + \pi \log 2}}{{2\pi }} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{{2G}}{\pi } - \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: These are all quite beneficial!

Answer (score 3):

@Gary has already provided the anwer to the problem via the integral. We can also find the solution in a different form, though it would be a heuristic (not rigorous) approach.
Using the [Frullani theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral), we can write the sum in the form

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n\bigg(\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}dx-\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-nx}(e^{\frac{x}{2}}-e^{-\frac{x}{2}})}{x}dx\bigg)$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^\infty n\,e^{-nx}\Big(1-\frac{(e^\frac{x}{2}-e^{-\frac{x}{2}})}{x}\Big)dx$$
We see that the integrand is well-defined at $x=0$ (equal to zeto at any $n$).
Changing the order of summation and integration, we define
$$S_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nn\,e^{-nx}=-\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\,e^{-nx}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{e^x+1}=-\frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}$$
and the initial sum is
$$S=-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}dx+2\int_0^\infty\frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\frac{\sinh\frac{x}{2}}{x}dx=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh^2t}\frac{dt}{t}$$
The second integral can be evaluated, for example, via the integration in the complex plane (closing the contour by a big half-circle of radius $R$ in the upper half-plane). Integrand declines rapidly enough, so the integral along this half-circle $\to0$ as $R\to\infty$.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh^2t}\frac{dt}{t}=\oint=2\pi i \operatorname{Res}_{z=\frac{\pi i}{2}+2\pi i k}\frac{\sinh z}{\cosh^2z}\frac{1}{z}\,,\, k=0,1,2...$$
$$\sinh\Big(\frac{\pi i}{2}+2\pi ik+\epsilon\Big)=i(-1)^k\Big(1+O(\epsilon^2)\Big)$$
$$\cosh\Big(\frac{\pi i}{2}+2\pi ik+\epsilon\Big)=i(-1)^k\Big(\epsilon+O(\epsilon^3)\Big)$$
$$\text{at}\, z=\frac{\pi i}{2}+2\pi i k\qquad\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi i}{2}+2\pi i k}\Big(1-\frac{\epsilon}{\frac{\pi i}{2}+2\pi i k}+O(\epsilon^2)\Big)$$
Taking all together and evaluating the residues
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh^2t}\frac{dt}{t}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2\pi}{\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)^2}\frac{(-1)^k}{(1+2k)^2}$$
$$S=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{\pi}\beta(2)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2 G}{\pi}$$

Comment: Wonderful! smart idea!

Comment: Nice solution! Minor point: you are missing a summation in the second line of the first displayed formula.

Comment: @mike, thank you!

Comment: @Gary, thank you. Correcting )

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, your sum is equal to $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left(1+n\ln\left(\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\right)\right)&=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \left(n \ln\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\right)-1\right)\\&=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n (2n\operatorname{arccoth} (2n)-1)\end{align}$$

which I show how to derive and determine generalised results in my question on
[$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n (mn \operatorname{arccoth}(mn)-1)$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4290994/general-form-for-sum-n-1-infty-1n-leftm-n-textarccoth-m-n)
by using the [Mittag-Leffler pole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) of $\csc (z)$ namely:
$$\csc(z) = \frac{1}{z} + 2z \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z^2 - \left(\pi n\right)^2}$$
and substituting it into the integral
$$2G=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \csc x\, dx$$